# Is there a directory or website indexing smaller travel guides?

Tags: online-resources, guidebooks

There are a lot of good travel guides out there that are either local or targeted to a specific group.

Example guides that appeal to me personally include things like [mpba](http://mpba.sk/en) Bratislava (map of "authentic" places), [USE-IT](http://www.use-it.travel/home) various cites in Europe (targeted to young backpackers), [Unlike](http://unlike.net/) various cities (targeted to yuppies).

Is there an aggregator, directory or website out there for finding sites like this?

Comment: Possibly worth rephrasing, one of the questions mentioned in [the help on NOT to ask](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is eliciting lists...

Comment: @MarkMayo thanks, is it ok that I'm sort of asking for a list? - I don't want the reply to be a list but maybe a link to a list.

Comment: I've tried editing it as well as your most recent edit. We'll see what the community says.  But it might be better if you told us what type of small guide you're after - Vegan's Guide to Jamaica or whatever - because currently you're after a list that could be thousands long - consider how many cities and towns there are in the world, and the limitless target markets.